# terminal will not allow upgrade of 1604 lts

Tags: apt, upgrade

Terminal reads

Dell-DM061:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: Try again, some background was holding a lock.

Answer (score 0):

If you just started your system, it may be searching for updates which creates the lock. Make sure you have not another instance of apt, apt-get or aptitude running in the background:

```
ps aux | grep -e apt -e dpkg | grep -v grep
```

If this command return some process, like in this example where I'm running synaptic package manager as a test:

```
ps aux | grep -e apt -e dpkg | grep -v grep
darent    5578  0.0  0.0  10948   968 ?        S    16:24   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/synaptic-pkexec
root      5579 20.0  1.0 814300 173360 ?       Sl   16:24   0:03 /usr/sbin/synaptic
```

You may have two options. Wait until the process finishes (keep repeating the command until there's no output) or kill it taking note of the number and executing:

```
sudo kill 5578 5579
```

With the number of the proces or processes. This will kill the process in a "clean" way. If it refuses to exit, you can force it adding the switch -9 to the order:

```
    sudo kill -9 5578 5579
```

But I'd recommend the first one just in case. Then, run the upgrade again:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, retried upgrade today all now is fine Rob Hughes